# Newbie needing some help with Wine and PlayonLinux

Tags: 16.04, wine, games, playonlinux

Alright, so I have not used Linux Ubuntu since probably 14.10, but I wanted to come back and was tired of Windows consistent crash and bugs. I like playing games on my PC, I have Wine and PlayonLinux. I am not as literate of the Linux world as I used to be. I don't want to ever switch back, but I am not sure how to get things rolling on here. This is the specs for my laptop.

RAM: 4GiB(3.8 usable)

Processor: Intel® Core™ i3-5005U CPU @ 2.00GHz × 4

Graphics: Intel® HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2)

I am running on 64bit Ubuntu. I tried installing Star Wars the Old Republic, but it keeps saying it can only run one instance at a time. Any feedback, tips, would be greatly appreciated. I am running Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1):

If you open Terminal and enter "top", you should see all your processes (like Task Mgr in Windows). You can "kill" a process (pid) that shouldn't be running.

Please clarify if you are using wine/play on Linux to play the game.

**To kill wine process use :**

```
wineserver -k9
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the error log, so we can see exactly what is going on? On thing i can think of is to kill the playonlinux process to ensure no other instance of it is running and try again:

```
sudo killall playonlinux
```

it's also possible that something went wrong in the installation, and i can tell from the supported software section on the playonlinux website, that star wars, the old republic still has a lot of issues: https://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-2135-Star_Wars_The_Old_Republic.html
If this is the case, i would advise you to remove the playonlinux drive for this program, and reïnstall it using the playonlinux guidelines.

Comment: I tried grabbing the Playonlinux log, but it was way to long, is there a different one, I should be looking for? I got it from the debugger.

Comment: it doesn't really matter how long it is, just throw it on pastebin and paste the link here :)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/xJDpgCFF

Comment: it doesn't really seem like there's a problem with the installation or anything, try the answer below, which might also help. And i advise to restart your system entirely, to make sure no other wine/playonlinux instance is running.
The only thing i can make up from your log is that the resource is unavailable, which is probably because you have more than one instance running

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I tried restarting before and it did not seem to work very well.  It just sits there with the terminal saying waiting for swtor and just stalls I guess.

Comment: try removing your playonlinux drive, and reïnstall using the playonlinux install script for swtor. also, try updating your system, wine install and playonlinux using sudo apt-get upgrade. i think a lot of your modules are missing, or outdated. the playonlinux log you posted is not complete. also, are you using a 32bit or 64bit wine install and playonlinux drive?

Comment: I tried sudo apt-get upgrade and I got this. https://pastebin.com/XCyrjqAz after that I did the next step in the terminal which the result is in the link as well.  I am running 64bit Ubuntu.

Comment: I also seen that I have OS updates and tried installing and got this.  Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f

Comment: I would run sudo apt-get autoremove first, and sudo apt-get clean. looks like you have dependency conflicts between 32bit and 64bit modules.

Comment: You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libp11-kit-gnome-keyring : Breaks: libp11-kit-gnome-keyring:i386 (!= 3.18.3-0ubuntu2) but 3.10.1-1ubuntu4 is installed
 libp11-kit-gnome-keyring:i386 : Breaks: libp11-kit-gnome-keyring (!= 3.10.1-1ubuntu4) but 3.18.3-0ubuntu2 is installed Same as before, mate. I am not sure what is going on with it. I have never experienced this type of issue before.

Comment: I would not recommend using apt-get -f install. The reason these dependencies are breaking is because you have 2 different versions of them. forcing the installation of them would only make it worse, I actually advise removing the 32bit version of them on your 64 bit ubuntu.